# zimbra is unable to start : Size error: Unable to determine enabled services from ldap

Tags: centos, ldap, zimbra

Im using Zimbra on CentOS on one server.
Then I moved all of the data to a new server by using the rsync command.
When I wanted to start Zimbra on the new server using 'zmcontrol start', it throws this error:

Size error: Unable to determine enabled services from ldap. Unable to determine enabled services.
Cache is out of date or doesn't exist.

I looked inside the zmcontrol file and found this function inside it :

```
  sub getEnabledServices {
  my $ldap_master_url=getLocalConfig("ldap_master_url");
  my $ldap_dn=getLocalConfig("zimbra_ldap_userdn");
  my $ldap_pass=getLocalConfig("zimbra_ldap_password");

  my %s = ();
  $s{"zmconfigd"} = "zmconfigd";

  my @ldap_masters=split(/ /, $ldap_master_url);
  my $master_ref=\@ldap_masters;
  my ($ldap, $result);
  unless ($ldap = Net::LDAP->new( $master_ref, timeout =>30 )) {
    warn "Connect: Unable to determine enabled services from ldap.\n";
    return getCachedServices();
  }
  unless ($result = $ldap->bind($ldap_dn, password => $ldap_pass)) {
    warn "Bind: Unable to determine enabled services from ldap.\n";
    return getCachedServices();
  }
  $result = $ldap->search(base => "cn=servers,cn=zimbra", filter => "cn=$localHostName", attrs => ['zimbraServiceEnabled']);
  if ($result->code) {
    warn "Search error: Unable to determine enabled services from ldap.\n";
    return getCachedServices();
  }
  my $size = $result->count;
  if($size != 1) {
    warn "Size error: Unable to determine enabled services from ldap.\n";
    return getCachedServices();
  }
  my $entry = $result->entry(0); 
  foreach my $value ($entry->get_value('zimbraServiceEnabled')) {
    $s{$value} = $value;
  }
  $result = $ldap->unbind;

  if (scalar keys %s > 0) {
    open (CACHE, ">$cache_file");
    foreach my $service (keys %s) {
      print CACHE "$service\n";
    }
    close(CACHE);
  }
  return \%s;
}
```

I dont really understand this code except that it throws error if size is not equal to 1. My question is where does it get the value from? So that I can look inside a working server and compare them.

Comment: The problem: the zimbra change the name of server, but not the cn on ldap service. You need change the services name in ldap or back to old name server and try start `/opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsetservername -n oldname && zmcontrol restart`.